# Laravel Handling POST Request As GET

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have written two routes in my routes.php

```
Route::get('/users/portfolio', [
    'as' => 'api.v1.users.portfolio',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@portfolio'
]);

Route::post('/users/portfolio', [
    'as' => 'api.v1.users.portfolio',
    'uses' => 'UsersController@portfolio'
]);
```

GET Route is used to show all info to user
Post Route is used to send that info in mail

If I Call
POST localhost:8000/api/v1/users/portfolio
Then It Works Fine
Result of print_r(request()->method())  is POST

But If I Call
POST localhost:8000/api/v1/users/portfolio/
(Note a slash in the end)
Then Laravel handles this as a GET Request
Result of print_r(request()->method())  is GET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trailing slash produces a redirect, which results in a GET.